# Minimize the expression $4x^2+(x+2y-6)^2+16y-23$

Tags: optimization

Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Find the smallest possible value of $4x^2+(x+2y-6)^2+16y-23$. What method should I use?

Comment: To complete the squares is always an option.

Comment: Possible hint: note that $4x^2$ and $(x+2y-6)^2$ are always $\geq 0$.

Comment: How to do it? It sounds easy but it is actually difficult? Is there any other method such as AM-GM inequality or Jensen's inequality?

Comment: Take the first partials to find all the stationary points. Then verify which are actual mins through the second partials.

Comment: I know how to take partial derivative but what's next? I only know about stationary point in scalar function but not vector-valued function.

Comment: @RayCheng Please show your progress so far.

Comment: $8x+2(x+2y-6)(1+2y')+16y'=0$ with respect to x

Comment: i have found $5$ and the equal sign holds if $$x=1,y=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: What is the method if I use completing squares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this function $f$. If a minimum $\mathbf{x}$ exists, then it should satisfy 
$$\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = 0$$
Calculating this gives us
$$f_x = 10x+4y-12=0$$
$$f_y = 8y+4x-8=0$$
Or, simplified,
$$5x+2y=6$$
$$x+2y=2$$
So $x=1,y=1/2$, and the minimum value is $f(1,1/2)=5$.

Comment: The gradient is zero, that "zero" is zero vector?

Comment: you have yet to prove that it is minumum not maximum.

Comment: you mean take the second partial derivative?